# Cut bash variable input after space

Tags: bash

I use this bash cmd / var to get the latest Android Studio download link for linux:

```sh
URL=$(wget "http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html" -O - | grep -o "https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/[0-9.]*/android-studio-[0-9.]*-linux.tar.gz")
```

When I echo out the var, I get this:

```sh
[root@fedora tmp]# echo $URL
https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/2020.3.1.22/android-studio-2020.3.1.22-linux.tar.gz https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/2020.3.1.22/android-studio-2020.3.1.22-linux.tar.gz
[root@fedora tmp]#
```

What can I do to have the link only onetime in the var, I tried it with `head`, `cut` and `awake` but nothing worked.

Comment: You're getting multiple links because the regex match multiple times (they're in one line because you don't use quotes when outputting the var). Assuming the first link will always be correct, adding `| head -n1` to your pipeline after the `grep` should do the trick. Pretty big assumption though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` returns more than one line (and `grep` is the filter on each lines). To accept only the first line use "`| head -1`" after the `grep` command :

`URL=$(wget --quiet "http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html" -O - | grep -o "https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/[0-9.]*/android-studio-[0-9.]*-linux.tar.gz" | head -1)`

I added "`--quiet" option to wget command for more readable output in a terminal.

Arnaud under GNU/Linux Fedora

Comment: without the `head` maybe `grep -om1`  ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the blank separating the two occurences of the URL seems not to behave as expected with all kind of commands.

Since I am not able to explain what is happening, I was about suggest you a workaround after downloading with `wget`; just issue:

```
URL=${URL%?https*}
```

to get rid of the second URL, and the mysterious char separating both occurences.

But when I saw the answer of Arnaud Valmary above, I have to recognize he found the right explanation and the correct solution. Credits to him.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Not an answer; just expanding on some other comments ...

When referencing a variable, and we don't get the expected result, consider looking at the command(s) used to generate what gets assigned to the variable.  In this case if we set aside the `URL=$(...)` assignment and just run the `wget|grep` at the command line:

```
$ wget "http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html" -O - 2>&1 | grep -o "https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/[0-9.]*/android-studio-[0-9.]*-linux.tar.gz
```

**NOTE:** I added `2>&1` to force several lines of stderr to go to stdout.

This generates the following:

```
https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/2020.3.1.22/android-studio-2020.3.1.22-linux.tar.gz
https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/2020.3.1.22/android-studio-2020.3.1.22-linux.tar.gz
```

Save this in the `URL` variable and we get:

```
$ URL=$(wget ... | grep ...)
$ typeset -p URL
declare -- URL="https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/2020.3.1.22/android-studio-2020.3.1.22-linux.tar.gz
https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/2020.3.1.22/android-studio-2020.3.1.22-linux.tar.gz"
```

Notice the variable has an embedded carriage return (ie, the data is stored as 2 lines).

Now, what's this look like from a `echo` point of view:

```
$ echo $URL        # no double quotes => prints everything on single line:
https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/2020.3.1.22/android-studio-2020.3.1.22-linux.tar.gz https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/2020.3.1.22/android-studio-2020.3.1.22-linux.tar.gz

$ echo "$URL"      # wrapped in double quotes and the embedded carriage return is maintained
https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/2020.3.1.22/android-studio-2020.3.1.22-linux.tar.gz
https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/2020.3.1.22/android-studio-2020.3.1.22-linux.tar.gz
```

Others have already addressed how to limit/filter what gets stored in `URL` ...